# I am trying to solve git conflict in the local feature branch but something strange is happening

Tags: git, github

When I do `git pull origin master` inside the local feature branch and fix conflicts. After running a `git status` it shows all the modified files by other people which are already merget with the remote master. Is that ok? How correctly can I pull changes from remote master in my local feature branch and then after solving the conflict only commit that file not the bunch of files which are pulled?

Comment: If you want to commit just one file, commit just that one file. Do you understand how to make a commit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## TL;DR

You really do want to keep their changes.

## Long

Your concept of how merging works in Git disagrees with how Git thinks that merging works.  In this particular case, I'm afraid Git will win.

Let's start with this part:

> ... only commit that [one] file ...

The first thing you need to realize is that in Git, *every commit holds every file*.  Commits don't save changes!  Instead, they save a full snapshot of *every file*, exactly as it is at the time you tell Git: *take a snapshot now*.

#### Commits

More specifically, each commit has a number: a big, ugly, random-looking *hash ID*.  Git will look up a commit by this number.  We'll worry about where we *get* these numbers later; for now, just assume that we can somehow magically find the right commit hash ID at any time.

Inside each commit, we find:

- a full copy of every file that Git knows about, stored in a compressed and de-duplicated fashion; and
- some *metadata*, such as the name and email address of the person who made the commit.

The entire commit is read-only, frozen for all time, including the file snapshots and the metadata.  The fact that the files are de-duplicated means that it's OK for each commit snapshot to have a full copy of every file, because if that copy matches any previous commit's copy, those commits are really just sharing one underlying frozen copy.

The fact that these files are frozen and de-duplicated, though, means two things: (a) neither you nor Git itself can *change* any previous commit, and (b) they're useless for getting any *new work* done.  So Git copies the frozen files out into ordinary everyday files that you *can* see and work with.  These files are in your *working tree* or *work-tree*.  This work-tree isn't actually *in* Git: it's just an area that's next to the repository, where you can see and work with files.  The files that are in the commits aren't these files: they're in a different format.

#### Git's index or staging area

Git makes a new snapshot from what Git calls, variously, the *index*, or the *staging area*, or sometimes—rarely these days—the *cache*.  These are all just terms for the same thing.  We'll go into this in more detail in a moment, because the index is important during merging.  But you can just think of the index as holding a copy of every file.

The index's "copy" of each file—"copy" in quotes because it's de-duplicated—is already in Git's special frozen and de-duplicated *format*, but because it's in the index, rather than in a commit, you *can* change it.  In particular, Git lets you replace the index copy wholesale.  That's what `git add` really does: it tells Git *make the index copy of this file match the work-tree copy*.  Git will squish down the work-tree copy, and de-duplicate it, making it ready to freeze into a new commit, and put this new copy into the index.  If the new copy matches any existing copy in any existing commit, it's now de-duplicated, so it's always ready to go.

#### Chains of commits

We mentioned above that each commit has some metadata.  Inside the commit's metadata, every commit stores the big ugly random-looking hash ID number of the *previous* commit.  So this means that once we have the right number for some commit, we can have Git itself find the right number of the *previous* commit.

In other words, given the hash ID of the *last* commit, Git itself can work backwards.  We can draw that like this:

```
... <-F <-G <-H   <-- somehow, we have to know H's hash ID
```

`H` here stands in for the hash ID of the *last* commit in the chain.  If we know the ID, Git can find the commit, and therefore get the frozen snapshot and the metadata.  Using that metadata, Git can find `G`'s hash ID, and use that to look up commit `G` and find *its* snapshot and metadata.

If we have Git compare the snapshot in `G` to the one in `H`, Git can tell us what *changed*.  That's very often just what we have Git do: `git log -p`, for instance, shows us what *changed*, but in fact, Git is just storing these snapshots.

Of course, using commit `G`, Git can find earlier commit `F`, too.  Git can then use that to find an even-earlier commit, and so on, all the way back to the very first commit ever.  These backwards links are the *parents:* each commit stores the hash ID of its own parent, and Git works backwards.

#### Branch names

There's just one problem though: where will we get the hash ID for commit `H`?  This is where *branch names* come in.  A branch name like `master` simply holds the hash ID of the *last* commit in the chain:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
```

To add a new commit to our `master`, we start by having Git extract snapshot `H`.  The files from the snapshot in `H` go into Git's index, and get un-frozen and reconstituted into usable form in our work-tree.  There, we can actually see and work with the files.  We make any changes we like, and then run `git add`.

The `git add` command copies an updated file back into Git's index.  Or, if a file is all-new, `git add` puts the all-new file in Git's index.  Either way, Git's index now has the frozen-format, ready-to-go, compressed and de-duplicated copy of this file, along with all the ready-to-go, already-de-duplicated copies of every other file too.  Now we run `git commit`.

The `git commit` command gathers together all the metadata Git needs for the new commit: our name and email address, a log message, the current date-and-time, and so on.  The *hash ID* to store with the *new* commit is the hash ID of the current commit, i.e., `H`.  Git makes a new snapshot from the files that are in Git's index, and now the new commit is ready to go.  Git writes it out, into its big database of every commit ever, and this assigns the new commit its new hash ID.<sup>1</sup>  For our drawing, though, we'll just call this new commit `I`, and draw it like this:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
            \
             I
```

Since commit `I` is now the *last* commit in the chain, `git commit` does its special trick now: it writes the hash ID of new commit `I` into the *name* `master`, so that we have:

```
...--F--G--H
            \
             I   <-- master
```

(and we can straighten out the kink in this drawing, which I only put in so that I could have the name `master` point to `H` before).

Note that no *existing* commit has changed.  None *can* change because of the way hash IDs work (see footnote 1).  New commit `I` points back to existing commit `H`.  The only things that *changed* were the addition of new commit `I`, and the branch name `master` itself.

---

<sup>1</sup>The hash ID of each commit is actually a cryptographic checksum of the full contents of that commit.  So writing out the new commit *is* what gets it the hash ID: we don't know, and cannot predict, what the new commit's hash ID will be until we have all the contents, including the date-and-time-stamps.

---

#### Merging, part 1: the setup

The fact that the index is ready to go into a new commit is *why* you can think of the index as *the next commit we plan to make*.  During merging, though, the index takes on an expanded role.

When you are using `git merge`—and your `git pull` command is running `git merge` for you, so you *are* using it—your goal is to make a new commit that's special in exactly one way.  This new commit is a *merge commit*.  Like any ordinary commit, it has a snapshot.  Like any ordinary commit, it has a parent commit hash ID.  What's special is that it has a *second* parent commit hash ID too.

While you have been working on *your* `master` branch, someone else, in some other Git repository, has been working on *his* `master` branch.  Your name `master` and his name `master` are two different names, just like you and he are different people.  Even if you both have the same first (or [given](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Given_name)) name, you're still two distinct people.

Some *commits*, however, are shared.  Those are the ones that have the same hash IDs.  For instance, you and the other guy may have both started out with:

```
...--G--H   <-- master
```

Since then, you added some new commits:

```
          I--J   <-- master
         /
...--G--H
```

But he, too, has added some new commits:

```
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- [his master]
```

#### Merging, part 2: pull begins with fetch

When you use `git pull`, you're really telling Git to run two separate Git commands.  The first command is always `git fetch`, which tells your Git to call up some other Git and obtain any new commits from them.  Your Git adds those commits to your repository, so that you now have this:

```
          I--J   <-- master
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- origin/master
```

Your Git's `origin/master` is your Git's way of remembering *their* Git's `master`: your Git knows that their Git has their `master` pointing to commit `L`.  Just before the `git fetch`, you didn't have `L`; now, after the `git fetch`, you do, and your `origin/master` remembers their `master`.

#### Merging, part 3: pull runs merge

Having run `git fetch`, the `git pull` command now runs a *second* Git command.  You can choose which second command it uses, but the usual default will be that your Git will run `git merge`, and that's what you've chosen here.

The `git merge` command is kind of complicated, but we'll look only at the true merge case here, and worry about only one complication, namely a simple merge conflict.  Before we get to the complication, though, let's look at what would happen if `git merge` *didn't* have a conflict.

Again, we start with:

```
          I--J   <-- master (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- origin/master
```

I've added the `(HEAD)` here to help remember what name we're working with.  Git uses this special name to tell which branch name you're using.  In this case, `origin/master` isn't actually a *branch* name,<sup>2</sup> but it's still nice to have the attached `(HEAD)` here.

Git now runs the equivalent of `git merge origin/master`.<sup>3</sup>  Our Git locates commit `L`.  Our Git knows that we're on `master` and that means commit `J`.  Our Git now uses the graph to find the *best common ancestor* of these two commits.  To do that, our Git starts at `J` and works backwards: `J`, `I`, `H`, and so on; and at the same time, starts at `L` and works backwards: `L`, `K`, `H`, and so on.  These two steps first share commit `H`.

This best shared commit, in this case commit `H`, is what `git merge` calls the *merge base*.  So for this merge, `H` is the merge base.

Now, remember that every commit has a full snapshot of every file, rather than some set of changes.  So what Git has to do now is run *two comparisons:*

- compare `H` vs `J`, to see what we changed; and
- compare `H` vs `L`, to see what they changed.

The merge command's job is to combine these two sets of changes.  If the combining goes well, `git merge` can make the final commit on its own: it takes the files from `H`—not from `J` or `L`, but from `H`—and applies the combined changes to those files.  This *keeps our changes and adds their changes*.  We don't lose anything in this process, and we don't lose their changes either.

Then, Git makes a new commit.  Again, this new commit is like any ordinary commit in most ways: it has a full snapshot and some metadata.  The snapshot is made with the *combined* changes as applied to what's (still) in `H`.  The metadata includes your own name and email address and a log message (the default one is not very good, but most people just use it anyway).  The only thing special about this new commit is that instead of just one parent `J` from our `master`, it has *two* parents.  The second parent is commit `L`, from our `git merge` command:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- master (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L   <-- origin/master
```

---

<sup>2</sup>Git calls this thing a *remote-tracking branch name*.  I like to drop the word *branch*, because it doesn't quite act like a branch name: calling it a *remote-tracking name* helps with the crazy levels of terminology re-use we get in Git.  We still have the somewhat-overloaded terms *remote* and *tracking* here, but at least we got rid of the badly-overloaded term *branch*.

<sup>3</sup>When you put the two steps together, it explains why, in `git pull origin master`, it's split up like this, but in `git merge`, it's just `git merge origin/master`.  Remember, `git pull` runs `git fetch` first.  This really wants the `origin` and `master` to be separate: it takes the *remote*, i.e., `origin`, and the branch name to hand *to* the remote, i.e., their `master`.  But having finished the fetch step, `git fetch` has created or updated our own `origin/master`, so for our `git merge`, we want `origin/master` with the slash in it.

---

#### Think about what you will see if you compare merge `M` to either parent

When the `git log -p` command shows you an ordinary commit, it compares that commit's snapshot to that commit's parent's snapshot:

```
...--P--C--...
```

Whatever is *different* in `P`-vs-`C` (parent-vs-child), is what happened in that commit.  But a merge commit has *two* parents.  Which comparison should Git make?

The answer that `git log` uses for this question is: *none at all*.  It just skips right over the comparing job.  It shows no differences.  That's the lazy way out, but it's OK as long as you know that `git log -p` is doing that.

A more clever idea is to run *two separate comparisons*, one for each parent.  If you compare `M` vs `J`, you'll see the changes that were *because of `origin/master` commits `K-L`*, as it were.  If you compare `M` vs `L`, you'll see the changes that were *because of `master` commits `I-J`*, as it were.  (Try this out and see.  It helps to run a few examples, to cement the idea into your head.)

(The `git show` command has an even-more-clever, perhaps-too-clever answer, where Git tries to *combine* multiple separate `git diff` outputs.  I won't go into any detail here as this answer is already quite long.)

#### Merging, part 4: simple conflicts

Suppose that after running:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-H> <hash-of-J>   # what we changed
git diff --find-renames <hash-of-H> <hash-of-L>   # what they changed
```

to handle our merge setup, Git finds that both we *and* they changed `main.py` and/or `README.md`, and that the changes we made to this file, or these files, conflict with each other?  That is, if we changed `red light` on line 42 to `green light`, and they changed it to `yellow light`, Git doesn't know which line to use.  **What Git will do for this case is to stop in the middle of the merge**, leaving a bit of a mess behind.  Our job is now to clean up this mess.

Remember before that we said that Git stores, in its index, a frozen-format de-duplicated file, ready to go into the next commit.  That's true for normal everyday situations, but during a conflicted merge, Git ends up storing not just one, but *three* of these frozen-format files, for each file.

That is, if there was a conflict in `README.md` because of a change we made on line 42, the index now contains *three* `README.md` files.  They're all named `README.md`, so we need some other way to tell them apart.  What Git does here is to use *slot numbers*.  Each file in Git's index is numbered:

- Slot zero is the normal everyday "no conflict" file.  This slot is now empty.
- Slot 1 holds the *merge base* copy of the file.  In this case, that's the copy from commit `H`.
- Slot 2 holds the `--ours` copy of the file, from the `HEAD` commit.  In this case, that's the copy from commit `J`.
- Slot 3 holds the `--theirs` copy of the file, from the commit we chose to merge.  In this case that's the copy from commit `L`.

**Your job is to put the *correct* copy of the file into slot zero.**  This will "resolve the conflict", and allow Git to move on.

Meanwhile, Git writes its own best attempt at merging the file to your work-tree.  You can use this copy of the file, which you can actually see and work with.  That's what I usually do myself.  Just edit the file until it's correct, then run `git add` on it.  The `git add` command will erase the three nonzero slot entries and copy the work-tree copy into the slot-zero copy.

If you like various merge tools, you can run `git mergetool`.  This command uses the index and the three copies of the file to run a third-party command.<sup>4</sup>  It then optionally runs `git add` for you as well.

When you are done merging conflicted files, the index will be back into its normal state: all entries will be slot-zero entries.  The `git status` command will tell you that all the conflicts are resolved and it's now possible to commit.  Running `git commit`, or `git merge --continue`,<sup>5</sup> will make the new commit as usual, using the files that are in Git's index; but Git will know that this new commit is a merge commit, and will give it the extra parent needed.

---

<sup>4</sup>While Git itself does not come with any merge tools, `git mergetool` knows how to run a small collection of third-party tools, and is willing to run any arbitrary command you like.  For details, see other StackOverflow questions and answers.

<sup>5</sup>The `git merge --continue` command merely makes sure that you're finishing a stopped merge, then runs `git commit`, so these do the same thing in the end.  The only reason to use `git merge --continue` is to make sure that you're really finishing a suspended merge.

---

#### How `git status` really works, or: why you want their changes

When you run `git status`, Git produces some preliminary information first, such as the name of the branch to which `HEAD` is attached (`on branch master`).  Then it goes on to inspect its index.

If you're in a suspended merge and have conflicts, Git will diagnose them here.  It can tell because there will be some entries in the index that have a nonzero staging slot number.  But if all entries are at stage zero, which is the more normal case, we'll see a more normal `git status` output here.  What Git does, though, is to run *two* comparisons, not just one.  These are the equivalent of two `git diff --name-status` commands:

- The first diff compares the `HEAD` commit vs the index.  For each file that is *the same*, Git says nothing at all.  For each file that is different, Git calls this file *staged for commit*.

  In other words, this is like running `git diff --cached --name-status`.  Files that will, in the new commit, differ from those in `HEAD`, will show up as staged for commit.  If you had a conflict in `README.md` to resolve, and you resolved it, and the resulting `README.md` is *different from that in commit `J`*, this file will show up here.  But if you *didn't* have a conflict in `main.py` because your Git took *their* changes to `main.py` when you had no changes to `main.py` yourself, `main.py` will show up here as well.
- The second diff compares the index vs the work-tree.  For each file that is *the same*, Git says nothing at all.  For each file that is different, Git calls this file *not staged for commit*.  In other words, this is like running `git diff --name-status`.

  If a file shows up in this list, it means that running `git add` on that file would copy something different into Git's index.  Once you do that, there's a pretty good chance that diffing the `HEAD` and index copies will show them to be different, i.e., this will have moved from "not staged" to "staged".

  If a file that shows up in this list has, in the work-tree, the *same data* that it has in `HEAD`, and you `git add` the file, the file will disappear from both lists.  Remember, to show up here, the index and work-tree copies must be different.  We're saying that the work-tree and `HEAD` copies match.  So if we copy the work-tree copy into the index copy, now all three must match.

Since this is all happening *before* you commit, you'll want the index copy of each file to represent the *combined changes* that will go into your new merge commit.  That means you want to *keep their changes* while also adding your changes.  You are currently comparing the proposed merge commit `M` to your existing commit `J`.

Once you do make this commit, `git log -p` will by default *not show any diff at all:* not against `J`, and not against `L` either.  To make `git log -p` show both diffs, add `-m` to the options (`git log -mp` or `git log -m -p`).

#### Untracked files and `.gitignore`

There's one last wrinkle that is worth mentioning here.  In Git, `git commit` builds a new commit from whatever files are in Git's index.  The files in your work-tree are irrelevant.  But: what if all the files that *are* in Git's index match files in your work-tree, but there are files in your work-tree that *aren't in Git's index at all?*

These files—the files in your work-tree that are not in Git's index—are your *untracked files*.  This is what the phrase *untracked file* **means** in Git: a file that exists right now, in your work-tree, but does not exist right now, in Git's index.  Because your work-tree is yours to fuss with—you can create and remove any file there any time—you can change the set of untracked files that way.  But you can also copy a *new* file into Git's index using `git add`, or remove a file from Git's index entirely using `git rm`.  So you can change what's in Git's *index* at any time, too.

The `git checkout` command, or the `git switch` command in Git 2.23 or later, will in general fill in both Git's index *and* your work-tree, from the files saved in some commit.  So usually after `git checkout`, these match, except for untracked files that Git didn't touch.  But through `git add`, `git rm` (perhaps with `--cached`), and ordinary file-creating or file-removing commands, you have control over what's tracked and what's untracked.  Tracked vs untracked does not depend on what's in some past commit *unless* you've just run `git checkout` on that commit.

Listing a file in `.gitignore` has no effect on whether that file is *currently* in Git's index.  A `git checkout` of a commit that *does* have a file whose name is listed, will still put that file into Git's index.  What listing a file in `.gitignore` does, really, is two<sup>6</sup> things:

- it makes `git status` shut up about the file, instead of whining that it's untracked; and
- it makes a `git add .` or similar en-masse *add lots of files* command *not* add the file, if it's not already in the index.

In a sense, then, this file should have been called `.git-do-not-complain-if-these-files-are-untracked-and-do-not-auto-add-them-with-en-masse-add-operations`, or something like that.  But that file name would be ridiculous, so it's just `.gitignore`.

---

<sup>6</sup>In an annoying and slightly dangerous twist, it does a third thing: in some relatively rare situations, it gives Git permission to destroy the contents of a work-tree file.

Comment: Thanks for replying. For the merge commit in this case should I use -m " some fix"? because when I do git commit it asks for a message

Comment: The `-m "message"` part is not required. If you omit it, Git will open your editor on a default message, the same way it does for any other commit. As I noted above: "the default [message] is not very good, but most people just use it anyway"—it's up to you if you want to construct something fancier, such as "merge the code that implements X Y and Z", or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's okay. You're resolving conflicts on the *merge commit*, the commit with two parents that actually accomplishes the merge. It's correct for the merge commit to contain all of the changes that are getting merged in. Unless those other changes are somehow relevant to the conflict you're resolving, you can just leave them alone.

Comment: Thanks for replying. So the question is if I  commit the changes I assume all those green-lighted files will be pushed to my pull request and get shown as a change while I changed only 1 file and other ones just pulled from remote master.

Comment: What commands should I use for only pushing that single fixed conflict file noth the all files pulled from remote?

Comment: @Dave your assumption is wrong. You don't need to do anything special.

Comment: So what is going to happen with others with all other green marked files if I commit the changes to my pull request?